# Visual Studio 2015 Toolbar Broken

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, sql-server-2016

It looks like my Visual Studio Tool bar is broken somehow this morning.  I am using VS2015 and also have sql server 2016 installed on this machine.  I am running on a mac, w/ Parallels on Windows 10.  Anyone ever seen this?  It looks like it is duplicating items and adding items from sql server management studio.  [image]

Thanks for the help,

Chris

Comment: Try uninstalling Visual Studio and install it again.

Comment: A glitch in the Matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay what worked for me was to "Repair" my install of Visual Studio.. I assume reinstall would work too but I didn't want to do that w/o trying quicker methods.

Steps: 
1. Go to add/remove programs
2. Find Visual Studio 2015
3. Right click on it and select repair.
4. Restart computer and all good.

Answer (score 2):

I've never seen anything like that before, but you can try resetting the toolbars back to default.

1. Tools (one of them) > Import and Export Settings.
2. Import selected environment settings.
3. Save your current settings if you want, or skip that step.
4. Choose something from "Default Settings", I like "General".
5. Uncheck "All Settings".
6. Check General Settings > Menu and Command Bar customization.

You could also try starting Visual Studio in "Safe Mode", by adding "/SafeMode" to the command line for "devenv.exe".  That should tell you if this is caused by an extension or not.

Comment: Great ideas and thanks for the help. I set the settings back to general and no luck.  I also ran VS in safe mode and it still looks the same.